# XML character encoding

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I'm generating a XML based on string like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder;
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // Use String reader  
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(txt)));

    TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
    Source src = new DOMSource(document);
    Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\xmlFileName.xml"));
    aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It generates the file but I'm having a problem with characters.

For instance, this line of the generated XML:

```
<msg_detalhe>NÃ&#131;Â£o Ã&#131;Â© permitida a presenÃ&#131;Â§a de caracteres</msg_detalhe>
```

Should be:

```
<msg_detalhe>Não é permitida a presença de caracteres</msg_detalhe>
```

Comment: The code looks OK. Is `txt` already corrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in XML content use CDATA...

```
<![CDATA[content]]>
```

Comment: <whatever><![CDATA[yourcontent]]></whatever>

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I don't know how to add this line to the generated XML...as I said, I'm a beginner =)

Comment: as you can see...I'm receiving a string and converting it to XML

Comment: i guess you need to search around for some functions maybe which generates the content of a node in the CDATA. i dont know java ;) i just know a bit about XML and this CDATA thing could solve your character encoding

Comment: no problem... i think it will solve it as this is kind of a "must" in xml content. but not 100% sure.. have luck finding your function

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a system property when running your program: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: just use utf-8 if the file is saved in utf-8 if its some ISO or whatever take that instead

Comment: `java <option> <classfile>` or `java -jar <option> <jarfile>`

Comment: the first element it: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`, should I use **ISO-8859-1**?

Comment: If you don't have to generate a specific encoding for some reason, UTF-8 should be fine.